# Angular How do redirection with lazy loading Routes and loadChildren

Tags: angular

I try to add lazy loading  in my project to improve the loading time of my site, but the rediction no longer works.

file app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dom', loadChildren: () => import('./dom/dom.module').then(m => m.DomModule) },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },

];
```

custom.module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateComponent,
    EditComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    ViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DomRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class DomModule { }
```

lazy routing

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '/index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: '/:Id/view', component: ViewComponent },
  { path: '/create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: '/:Id/edit', component: EditComponent } 
];
   

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DomRoutingModule { }
```

when I enter dom url 'dom' I am redirected to localhost/index with error 404

when i change redirectTo: '/index' to 'dom/index'  i'm not redirected, it stays on localhost/dom

when i change path: '/index' to 'dom/index' and redirectTo: 'dom/index'  i'm redirected to localhost/dom/dom/index

Comment: I don’t think your paths should start with a slash?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are being redirected to `localhost/index` is because in the routing configuration of DomModule, you have specified `redirectTo: '/index'`.

**Angular treats `/` as the base route** i.e root path of your application. Therefore, specify `redirectTo:'index'` & update your routes by removing `/`.

For a lazy router, or any route, you should only specify the route name without preceding `/`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: ':Id/view', component: ViewComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: ':Id/edit', component: EditComponent } 
];
```

With this configuration now, you are telling Angular to redirect to `dom/index` i.e. relative to the current URL when the user visits `<yourdomain or localhost>/dom`.

Here is a working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3sp9t?file=src/app/dom/dom.module.ts